# Android: Package file with app in internal storage?

Tags: android

I want to package a java object saved as a data file with my application, and then overwrite it later. Where can I place this file in my app that I will have write access to it within the app? Is there any way to package it with the app so that it is in my private internal memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in the app as an asset or a raw resource. Then on first run of the application, copy it to internal storage as a private file. If read-only access is sufficient, you can read it directly from assets/resources.